# Reflection API for maps

Tags: protocol-buffers, proto, protobuf-java

I would like to set the value of a field which is of the type map using the reflection api for a protobuf message.

I have tried using the set field method as shown below. This does not seem to work. I can make it work by using the suggestion in [Filling up a map field in Proto using reflection API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43364297/filling-up-a-map-field-in-proto-using-reflection-api?answertab=oldest#tab-top). But this not seem to be a nice solution!

```proto
message OuterMessage {
  map<string, InnerMessage> mapInner = 1;
}
```

```java
Map<String, InnerMessage> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("R1", im1);
map.put("R2", im2);
OuterMessage.newBuilder().setField(fieldDescriptor, map);
```

I am getting the error,

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.base/java.util.List
```

Which is understandable when i look at the implementation. But how else would i set a map?

Comment: By now, there's no better way to do that. The Reflection API for map is still private. Check [this issue](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/1322) for details.